# Exception handling when dealing with absolute/relative path to python script

Tags: python, linux, exception

I have python script without shebang (it's matter). And when I run it with relative path all is ok, exception raising direct to terminal:

```
$ python -V
Python 2.6.6
$ cat 1.py
import os

print os.getcwd()

a=b

print c
$ python ./1.py
/home/user
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./1.py", line 5, in <module>
    a=b
NameError: name 'b' is not defined
$
```

But it raises exception only when type Control-C if specify absolute path to script (Note ^C symbol in code snippet before Traceback section):

```
$ python /home/user/1.py
/home/user
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/v-yyushyn/1.py", line 5, in <module>
    a=b
NameError: name 'b' is not defined
$
```

Firstly, I thought that it behavior depends on 'absolute path' runs in subshell, but after short investigation I found that both launches runs in same shell.

Yes, it's possible to place a shebang and run script without specifying interpreter. But it interesting why behavior is different in case of absolute/relative path to script.

Have anybody suggestions about it?
Thank you

Update: python -v /home/user/1.py

```
# installing zipimport hook
import zipimport # builtin
# installed zipimport hook
# /usr/lib64/python2.6/site.pyc matches /usr/lib64/python2.6/site.py
import site # precompiled from /usr/lib64/python2.6/site.pyc
# /usr/lib64/python2.6/os.pyc matches /usr/lib64/python2.6/os.py
import os # precompiled from /usr/lib64/python2.6/os.pyc
import errno # builtin
import posix # builtin
# /usr/lib64/python2.6/posixpath.pyc matches /usr/lib64/python2.6/posixpath.py
import posixpath # precompiled from /usr/lib64/python2.6/posixpath.pyc
# /usr/lib64/python2.6/stat.pyc matches /usr/lib64/python2.6/stat.py
import stat # precompiled from /usr/lib64/python2.6/stat.pyc
# /usr/lib64/python2.6/genericpath.pyc matches /usr/lib64/python2.6/genericpath.py
import genericpath # precompiled from /usr/lib64/python2.6/genericpath.pyc
# /usr/lib64/python2.6/warnings.pyc matches /usr/lib64/python2.6/warnings.py
import warnings # precompiled from /usr/lib64/python2.6/warnings.pyc
# /usr/lib64/python2.6/linecache.pyc matches /usr/lib64/python2.6/linecache.py
import linecache # precompiled from /usr/lib64/python2.6/linecache.pyc
# /usr/lib64/python2.6/types.pyc matches /usr/lib64/python2.6/types.py
import types # precompiled from /usr/lib64/python2.6/types.pyc
# /usr/lib64/python2.6/UserDict.pyc matches /usr/lib64/python2.6/UserDict.py
import UserDict # precompiled from /usr/lib64/python2.6/UserDict.pyc
# /usr/lib64/python2.6/_abcoll.pyc matches /usr/lib64/python2.6/_abcoll.py
import _abcoll # precompiled from /usr/lib64/python2.6/_abcoll.pyc
# /usr/lib64/python2.6/abc.pyc matches /usr/lib64/python2.6/abc.py
import abc # precompiled from /usr/lib64/python2.6/abc.pyc
# /usr/lib64/python2.6/copy_reg.pyc matches /usr/lib64/python2.6/copy_reg.py
import copy_reg # precompiled from /usr/lib64/python2.6/copy_reg.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/abrt_exception_handler.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/abrt_exception_handler.py
import abrt_exception_handler # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/abrt_exception_handler.pyc
import encodings # directory /usr/lib64/python2.6/encodings
# /usr/lib64/python2.6/encodings/__init__.pyc matches /usr/lib64/python2.6/encodings/__init__.py
import encodings # precompiled from /usr/lib64/python2.6/encodings/__init__.pyc
# /usr/lib64/python2.6/codecs.pyc matches /usr/lib64/python2.6/codecs.py
import codecs # precompiled from /usr/lib64/python2.6/codecs.pyc
import _codecs # builtin
# /usr/lib64/python2.6/encodings/aliases.pyc matches /usr/lib64/python2.6/encodings/aliases.py
import encodings.aliases # precompiled from /usr/lib64/python2.6/encodings/aliases.pyc
# /usr/lib64/python2.6/encodings/utf_8.pyc matches /usr/lib64/python2.6/encodings/utf_8.py
import encodings.utf_8 # precompiled from /usr/lib64/python2.6/encodings/utf_8.pyc
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Sep 11 2012, 08:34:23)
[GCC 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
/home/user
/usr/lib64/python2.6/os.pyc
/home/user/1.py
False
<function <lambda> at 0x7fa22e784c08>
dlopen("/usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-dynload/syslog.so", 2);
import syslog # dynamically loaded from /usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-dynload/syslog.so
# /usr/lib64/python2.6/traceback.pyc matches /usr/lib64/python2.6/traceback.py
import traceback # precompiled from /usr/lib64/python2.6/traceback.pyc
# /usr/lib64/python2.6/socket.pyc matches /usr/lib64/python2.6/socket.py
import socket # precompiled from /usr/lib64/python2.6/socket.pyc
dlopen("/usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-dynload/_socketmodule.so", 2);
import _socket # dynamically loaded from /usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-dynload/_socketmodule.so
dlopen("/usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-dynload/_ssl.so", 2);
import _ssl # dynamically loaded from /usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-dynload/_ssl.so
dlopen("/usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-dynload/cStringIO.so", 2);
import cStringIO # dynamically loaded from /usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-dynload/cStringIO.so
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/1.py", line 10, in <module>
    a=b
NameError: name 'b' is not defined
# clear __builtin__._
# clear sys.path
# clear sys.argv
# clear sys.ps1
# clear sys.ps2
# clear sys.exitfunc
# clear sys.exc_type
# clear sys.exc_value
# clear sys.exc_traceback
# clear sys.last_type
# clear sys.last_value
# clear sys.last_traceback
# clear sys.path_hooks
# clear sys.path_importer_cache
# clear sys.meta_path
# clear sys.flags
# clear sys.float_info
# restore sys.stdin
# restore sys.stdout
# restore sys.stderr
# cleanup __main__
# cleanup[1] cStringIO
# cleanup[1] encodings
# cleanup[1] site
# cleanup[1] syslog
# cleanup[1] abc
# cleanup[1] _codecs
# cleanup[1] _warnings
# cleanup[1] zipimport
# cleanup[1] encodings.utf_8
# cleanup[1] codecs
# cleanup[1] socket
# cleanup[1] signal
# cleanup[1] traceback
# cleanup[1] posix
# cleanup[1] encodings.aliases
# cleanup[1] exceptions
# cleanup[1] abrt_exception_handler
# cleanup[1] _ssl
# cleanup[1] _socket
# cleanup[2] copy_reg
# cleanup[2] posixpath
# cleanup[2] errno
# cleanup[2] _abcoll
# cleanup[2] types
# cleanup[2] genericpath
# cleanup[2] stat
# cleanup[2] warnings
# cleanup[2] UserDict
# cleanup[2] os.path
# cleanup[2] linecache
# cleanup[2] os
# cleanup sys
# cleanup __builtin__
# cleanup ints: 19 unfreed ints
# cleanup floats
```

Comment: I cannot see where `b` comes from or `c` for that matter

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I guess it's there just to raise an exception.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham It's not a real prod code, only for example. famousgarkin is right - it's there just to raise an exception

Comment: Add a line `print os.__file__` to the script and try again. Add it after the `import os`.

Comment: @morsik It should behave exactly the same no matter which path you use. Maybe there's something else in your environment that interferes?

Comment: @martijn-pieters os.__file__ returns /usr/lib64/python2.6/os.pyc in both cases. And situation isn't changed - absolute path relies on Ctrl-C

Comment: @morsik: there was a chance that a *different* `os` was being imported, one that adds an `raw_input()` call or similar. The behaviour is *not typical*. Moreover, the program appears to hang *after* the `print os.getcwd()` has already executed.

Comment: @famousgarkin on windows behavior the same, but windows relies on file extension .py rather then Linux shebang

Comment: @morsik: does either `import sitecustomize` or `import usercustomize` work? If so, what is their `__file__` attribute look like? If either works, what are the contents of either of those files?

Comment: @martijn-pieters `ImportError: No module named sitecustomize`, `ImportError: No module named usercustomize`. `__file__` is '1.py' and '/home/user/1.py' in relative/absolute path cases respective. I've tried on my VM and it work fine, but in customer env this strange behavior take place

Comment: @morsik: yes, it is very strange, which is why I am stepping through the possibilities here. Next one: `import sys; print sys.excepthook is sys.__excepthook__`. Should print `True`; if it doesn't, `print sys.excepthook` to take a look at what that might be.

Comment: @martijn-pieters `False`
`<function <lambda> at 0x7fbc5ac09c08>
`

Comment: @morsik: right, so *something* replaced the exception hook. We are getting somewhere! Next step: `python -v /home/user/1.py` and add that to the post.

Comment: @martijn-pieters added in question description

Comment: @morsik: bingo; this is CentOS, isn't it.

Comment: @martijn-pieters yep, CentOS release 6.3 (Final)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The client has the [`abrt` automatic bug reporting tool](https://github.com/abrt/abrt/wiki/ABRT-Project) installed. It intercepts exceptions and sends them to a dedicated process to track crashes. It is a common add-on on CentOS and Redhat systems (also see the [Redhat documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/ch-abrt.html))

It is that process that hangs, and requires you to use an interrupt to bypass it.

See the [`abrt` configuration documentation](https://github.com/abrt/abrt/wiki/Configuration); introspect what it is doing and adjust it to *not hang*. The [`abrt` FAQ](https://github.com/abrt/abrt/wiki/FAQ) may also be of help; there are commands listed there to check on the status of the service, for example.

I can see from the [hook `abrt` installs](https://github.com/abrt/abrt/blob/d6ea76b818a638d345509ea724050bf65f57c349/src/hooks/abrt_exception_handler.py.in#L227) that scripts with a relative path are ignored; it only handles exceptions in scripts with an absolute path (so `/home/user/1.py`), which is why you are seeing this issue only then.

From the same code we can see that it'll log messages to `syslog`; the defaults are used so they'll end up in `/var/log/user.log`; look out for the script filename there (`1.py`).

Most likely the socket connection to the `abrtd` daemon is hanging. Why the socket hangs can be due to any number of reasons, [including faulty network firmware](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=848681).

Comment: this module runs in both cases, and `dlopen("/usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-dynload/syslog.so", 2);` runs right before `a=b`. Diffs after `import syslog # dynamically loaded from /usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-dynload/syslog.so`, why they're have place?

Comment: @morsik: the hook always imports the `syslog` module, but scripts with a relative path are ignored in the hook.

Comment: Thx, great. You background worthy of respect